# Constant functions can't be used on constant referenced object?

Tags: c++

I'm not entirely sure how to describe my issue at all.

Basically I have a function that checks to see if my rectangle contains a different rectangle, however, when I attempt to use my functions such as `getX` and `getY` I am met with: `Error: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function object type is: const Rectangle2D`.

My function is below.

```
const bool Rectangle2D::contains(const Rectangle2D &r) {
    const double x = r.getX();
    const double y = r.getY();
    const double width = r.getWidth();
    const double height = r.getHeight();
}
```

All of my `get` functions are constant, example:

```
const double Rectangle2D::getX() {
    return x;
}
```

And in my class it the function is defined as `const bool contains(const Rectangle2D &r)`.

If more information is needed let me know. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction.

Comment: `bool contains(const Rectangle2D &r) const` is the correct syntax for the constant function.

Comment: ... and the `const bool` for the return type is unneeded.; `bool` will suffice. likewise for your other `get()`'ers. It looks like you're just putting your `const` in the wrong place. Try the other end =P

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me clear this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put const after the function name and parameter list, before the curly brace or semicolon. So in your class you should have

```
double getX() const;
```

And then when you implement it, you should have

```
double Rectangle2D::getX() const {
    return x;
}
```

You'll need to do the same with the contains function and any other functions you want to be able to use on a const Rectangle2D.

Comment: He probably also wants 'contains' to be const as well and not returning a const bool.

Answer (score 2):

Done this way:

```
const double Rectangle2D::getX() {
    return x;
}
```

this is a *non-const* function that returns a constant double.

To make it a const function, do it like this:

```
double Rectangle2D::getX() const {
  return x;
}
```